# How to stop logs getting created in azure container when using outlook in azure logic apps?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-logic-apps

Created a logic app that could retreive a email attachment from the email and store it in the azure blob storage.

[image]

But whenever the outlook action runs it creates a random container like-flow29ed423b44234v2nhnjg4234v4h23 in the blob storage and inside it has some json files. I need these logs to be stop created or it should be created in a particular container which I mention but sadly I couldn't find any option that

If I remove the outlook activity from the logic app its not getting created.

Comment: Can you provide the flow of your logic app long with the images of it

Comment: @SwethaKandikonda- I have added the workflow image of the logic apps  in the above description. First it has recurrence where its scheduled to run one time a week,outlook activity retrieves the file from the email,added a for each loop and create blob is to store the the extracted file from the email

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your flow I can see it has 2 triggers but you can directly use `When a new email arrives (V3)` trigger directly. Since the flow gets triggered every time a mail receives in the inbox or the selected folder. While to achieve your requirement, you can follow something as below.

[image]

Blob Content is as below
`base64ToString(body('Get_Attachment_(V2)')?['contentBytes'])`

*Note:* Make sure the container is already created in your blob storage.

##### Results:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks the solution which is provided is working now!!